# When creating a new instance of Snowflake hosted on AWS, is the data storage to S3 automatically setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've created a new instance of Snowflake hosted on AWS. Is the data storage component in S3 automatically setup? If not, what pieces of information do I need to configure it (assuming I already have an S3 instance created)

Comment: [Key Concepts & Architecture - Data Storage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#database-storage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage that Snowflake uses to store and maintain the databases is created automatically by Snowflake.  You will see the amount of storage used by each table in the tables listing.

If you need to load source files from an S3 bucket, you will need to create an external stage, and then run the 'COPY INTO' command.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the quick answer. So I'd only need to use COPY INTO if I'm loading something like .csv or .json files into Snowflake?

Otherwise using a platform like FiveTran will auto load into Snowflake's pre-created storage. Correct?

Comment: correct!  ETL tools like FiveTran will auto load into snowflake storage, using the target DB/schema/table that you specify

Answer (score 1):

In order to set up the External Stage using AWS S3, you have got 3 options:

Option 1: [Configuring a Snowflake Storage Integration to Access Amazon S3](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html)

Option 2: [Configuring an AWS IAM Role to Access Amazon S3 — Deprecated](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-aws-iam-role.html)

Option 3: [Configuring AWS IAM User Credentials to Access Amazon S3](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-aws-iam-user.html)